# UIView: addConstraint fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION unless no-op constraints() is called first

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have a layout that requires updating the multiplier from (indirect) data from the model.  In short, I can remove the constraint and create a modified constraint from it.  When I attempt to add the constraint back again via addConstraint(...) though, I get the titular EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

Strangely, when I added debug code to inspect the existing constraints, the problem disappears. Is there any possible interpretation of this problem, other than yet another iOS / Swift bug?

My code looks (something) like this:

```
    myView?.constraints() // crashes without this line, only works with it
    myView?.removeConstraint(self.myConstraint)
    self.myConstraint = myConstraint.withMultiplier(someModelDoubleValue / 14.0)
    myView?.addConstraint(self.myConstraint) // crashes here without first line
```

Has anybody else done this - it seems so trivial that I can't imagine that it would not have been tested.

Note that the withMultiplier method is just my functional inspired extension method, but it has been tested and otherwise works.  For full disclosure though, it looks like this:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func withMultiplier(newMultiplier:CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: firstItem, attribute: firstAttribute,
            relatedBy: relation,
            toItem: secondItem, attribute: secondAttribute,
            multiplier: newMultiplier, constant: constant)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `self.myConstraint` is a `weak` reference with "implicitly unwrapped optionals" like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

It's deallocated at `myView?.removeConstraint(self.myConstraint)`. then, at `myConstraint.withMultiplier(`, `myConstraint` is `nil`, that causes the error.

If so, just omit `weak` or use temp variable like:

```
var constraint = self.myConstraint
myView?.removeConstraint(constraint)
constraint = constraint.withMultiplier(someModelDoubleValue / 14.0)
myView?.addConstraint(constraint)
self.myConstraint = constraint
```

Why `myView?.constraints()` solves the problem? that is, `constraints()` returns `NSArray` with `autorelease()`ed. That array has strong references to the constraints, and lives within current autorelease pool.

Comment: Yes, that constraint is indeed weak - derived from Storyboard, and your argument makes sense.  I just mangled my project with an undead git repository, but when I'm awake in the morning I will retest.  Thanks.